# Delete localStorage after 1 hour and re-fetch data

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I just learned about localStorage and wrote a script to cache the data from an ajax request in local storage.

Can we set a timestamp on the data in localStorage so that after 2 hours it will be deleted and a new ajax request is sent to grab data?  This way if the data is updated it, the user can get access to the new data.

Here's a fiddle to my current code to cache the data in local storage.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q77RL/

Here's the code as well:

```
if ( localStorage && localStorage.getItem('aGithub') ) {
  console.log('if statement using local storage');
  console.log (JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('aGithub') ));
}
else {
  console.log('else statment using ajax');
  $.ajax({
    url : 'https://api.github.com/users/paulirish', //just a test because Paul Irisih is awesome!
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (data) {
        if ( localStorage ) {
            localStorage.setItem( 'aGithub', JSON.stringify(data) );    
        }
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Store an entry in the localstorage that defines the last access time, then compare that to current time each time it is accessed. If n time has passed, clear it and get fresh data.

Comment: Consider the usage of sessionStorage because a very limited localStorage does not really make sense...

Comment: @redaxmedia I understand that 1 hour localStorage may not make sense, and that sessionStorage would be preferable in that instance.  But it is just an abritrary time I am working on.  Instead of an hour, consider localStorage that should be removed if it is a month old.  sessionStorage would not seem to work well for that since it would expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to mention it. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store an entry in the localstorage that defines the last access time, then compare that to current time each time it is accessed. If n time has passed, get fresh data.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q77RL/2/

```
var myGithub = {
    lifespan: 1*10*1000, //10 seconds, change this to 1 hour
    def: $.Deferred(function(def){
        if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('myGithub')) {
            def.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myGithub')))
        }
        else {
            def.resolve({});
        }
    }).promise(),
    fetchData: function(){
        console.log(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('myGithubTS'), 10),parseInt($.now(), 10),this.lifespan);
        if (localStorage && (!localStorage.getItem('myGithub') || !localStorage.getItem('myGithubTS') || parseInt($.now(), 10) - parseInt(localStorage.getItem('myGithubTS'), 10) > this.lifespan)) {
            this.def = $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.github.com/users/paulirish', //just a test because Paul Irisih is awesome!
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (localStorage) {
                        localStorage.setItem('myGithub', JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }).then(function(){
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myGithub'));
            });
            localStorage.setItem('myGithubTS', $.now());
        }
        return this.def;
    }
};

var counter = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    myGithub.fetchData().done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    if (counter == 40) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    counter++;
},1000)
```

The code above will only hit the api once per 10 seconds. Change the lifespan property to change how long the duration is. To get new data, simply use

```
myGithub.fetchData().done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

You can use that as many times as you want and it will only hit the api once per 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks!  I had not seen promise() before.